# How to change the root directory of the apache server for Django project

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run my Django project on the server using Apache2, the server is ubuntu VPS, the project runs normally using `runserver` command, but I can't do it normally using apache, as it gives me this page:

[image]

And of course, the default document directory for apache2 is `var/www/html`, but I want to use my own directory.

So here are my files :

**the active config file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my_domain.com
        ServerAlias localhost
        Alias /static /path/to/my/project/static/
        WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/wsgi.py
        <Directory /path/to/my/project/>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /path/to/my/project/
        ErrorLog /path/to/my/project/error.log
        CustomLog /path/to/my/project/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**apache2.conf**

```
<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /path/to/my/project/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What's wrong with those files ?

Comment: You've definitely restarted apache after editing those files? At first glance, they look fine.

Comment: Also, FYI this question is better suited for serverfault.com. It doesn't actually have anything to do with Django.

Comment: @GregKaleka yes I did restart, after edits .. and thank you for this serverfault.com hint, I never know it exists already before now.